# Web scraper script - How can I make it run quicker?

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping

I just started with python 3 and love reading light novels, so the first python project I made is a script which web scrapes & downloads my favourite light novel.

Everything works fine so far but it is really slow, especially checking whether a chapter is actually in the folder and downloading the chapters.

Right now the script needs 17.8 minutes to check and download 694 chapters.

Are there any ways to at least speed up the checking process? Because all the actual chapters only have to be downloaded once.

https://github.com/alpenmilch411/LN_scrape/blob/master/LN_scraper.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import getpass

#Gets chapter links
def get_chapter_links(index_url):
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    url_list = []
    for url in links:
        if 'http://www.wuxiaworld.com/cdindex-html/book' in str(url):
            url_list.append((url.get('href')))
    return url_list

#Gets chapter content
def get_chapters(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    chapter_text = soup.find_all('div',{'class':"entry-content"})
    #Puts chapter text into 'chapter'-variable
    chapter = ''
    for c in chapter_text:
      #Removing 'Previous Next Chapter'
      content = c.text.strip()                              # strip??
      chapter += content.strip('Previous Next Chapter')     # strip??
    return chapter

#Gets title of chapter
def get_title(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find_all('h1',{'class':'entry-title'})
    chapter_title = ''
    for l in title:
       chapter_title += l.text
    return chapter_title

#Gets title of story
def get_story_title(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    story = soup.find_all('h1',{'class':"entry-title"})
    story_title = ''
    for content in story:
       story_title += content.text
    return story_title



#url on which links can be found
links = 'http://www.wuxiaworld.com/cdindex-html/'


#Checks whether a directory already exists and creates a new one if necessary
story_title = get_story_title(links)
path = '/users/{}/documents/'.format(getpass.getuser())+'{}'.format(story_title)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
link_list = get_chapter_links(links)
#Copys chapters into text file
for x in link_list:
    #Checks whether chapter already exists
    #TODO Make checking process quicker
    chapter_title = get_title(str(x)).replace(',','') + '.txt'
    if not os.path.isfile(path + '/' + chapter_title):
        story_title = get_story_title(links)
        chapter_text = get_chapters(str(x))
        file = open(path + '/' + chapter_title, 'w')
        file.write(chapter_text)
        file.close()
        print('{} saved.'.format(chapter_title.replace(',','')))

print('All chapters are up to date.')
```

Comment: Asynchronous requests. Check out a library like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Sam Please vote to close because the question is too broad. "Belongs on Code Review" is not a valid close reason.

Comment: You appear to be doing a lot of extraneous re-downloading of pages.  For example, "get_story_title(links)" in your loop is downloading and parsing the same content from http://www.wuxiaworld.com/cdindex-html/ each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use lxml with  BeautifulSoup. It is faster than html.parser

Comment: Script needs 8.6 minutes now for checking and downloading all files. Great improvement. Thanks!